# Compute coordinates of vector line?

Tags: qgis

I have a set of vector lines (which represent translation vectors for georeferencing).
Based on the layer CRS, how can I compute the coordinates of each line in an attribute table ?

*i.e (Xmax-Xmin; Ymax-Ymin) for each line.*

I have managed to get the line length with *$length* in the expression editor but I am struggling with other geometrical parameters.

**Edit**: I am looking to "store the formula" within the layer. The idea is to keep these values automatically updated with the geometry. (Auto)update should happen if a new line is added or modification of the current geometry is done.

Comment: About your recent edition, look at [virtual fields](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html#creating-a-virtual-field) (stores the formula but not within the layer). About the `$length()` function, it calculates the ellipsoidal length, use `length( $geometry)` instead if you want the planimetric one (probably not so). About the `(Xmax-Xmin; Ymax-Ymin)` example, it is assumed to be a string of characters because a pair of values can not be attributed to a single numeric field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the Field Calculator. Open the attribute table of your line layer and select the Open Filed Calculator icon from the toolbar. I use an OSM road layer.

[image]

In the Field Calculator window create a new column of decimal type, in the Geometry group of functions you can find x_min, x_max, y_min, y_max functions. To create a column with x_range of features use the next screenshot:

[image]

You can create a column for y_range in a similar way.

Comment: Thanks:  that is the method I was after but I was missing _$geometry_ to call the proper entity.

Comment: Is there a method to automatically compute these parameters for each line created within this layer as soon as they are created ?

Comment: or update automatically when the geometry is modified ?

Comment: See this post https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/178355/pyqgis-editing-a-feature-is-it-possible-to-set-a-listener or user virtual fields (virtual fields are calculated when you open the attribute table) which is technically simpler but slower.

Answer (score 3):

For QGIS 3.x, the formula in the field calculator is :

```
'(' || x_max($geometry) || '-' || x_min($geometry) || '; ' || y_max($geometry) || '-' || y_min($geometry) || ')'
```

Answer (score 3):

Following [J.Monticolo](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/93097/j-monticolo)'s answer, yet another expression is:

```
'(' || bounds_width($geometry) || '; ' || bounds_height($geometry) ||')'
```

Comment: kFly didn't say if (s)he want (Xmax-Xmin) as text or the result of subtraction (q.e.d. width or height). In case of text result, my solution is the good one, in the case of substraction, it's the Kazuhito's one.

Comment: I want actually the numerical value, but thanks for underlining up this difference